# Allow multicast packages from the bridge to wire in KVM

Tags: networking, kvm, bridge, multicast

On a CentOS 6.5 host, I have a couple of guests - Ubuntu 12.04 and CentOS 6.5.
The Ubuntu guest is generating mcast traffic that is visible via a `tcpdump` on the br3 interface. It is also visible on the other VM.

It is **not** on the associated eth3 interface, nor does it make it out the wire to other hosts.

We've been through [bridged networking with kvm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8673/bridged-networking-with-kvm) and this:

```
$ sed -I 's/^\(net.ipv4.ip_forward =\).*/\1 1/' /etc/sysctl.conf; sysctl -p
```

Along with these articles titled:

- [Centos 6.5 KVM issue with bridged interface to virtual machine](http://blog.pdurante.com/2013/12/05/centos-6-5-kvm-issue-with-bridged-interfaces-to-windows-guest/)
- and setting `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter` to `2`, via this articled, titled: [Why does Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 and above invalidate / discard packets when the route for outbound traffic differs from the route of incoming traffic?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/53031)
- ... and a few other things.

Does anyone have anything else?

Answer (score 0):

We do not understand what was under SELinux control, but something was and simply turning off selinux and rebooting got it working.

SELinux: Secure or Useable. Pick one.

Comment: Did you try running with "Permissive' settings, and simply following the popups to enable whatever selinux was complaining about?